# Dynatrace and iis issue

Tags: asp.net, iis, dynatrace

We have **dynatrace** installed in our 4 servers but out of 4 server 1 server is behaving weird after installing Dynatrace, the asp.net application is not working , it is not loading any JS file, css file ..but same application is just working fine on other servers, I can;t see any difference in servers.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some things to check:

a) Does the dynatrace agent connect for that 4th machine? -> you can see that in the Agent Overview dashlet

b) if it does - check the agent log files for that agent and check if there is anything indicating a problem. You can get to these log files from the agent overview dashlet via the context menu of that agent entry

c) make sure all 4 IIS AppPools run under the same user account that has privileges to load the dynatrace agent. the agent is installed in your program files\dynatrace directory. could it be that the one IIS uses a different windows user account for that apppool?

d) check your windows event viewer for any problems

Also - feel free to post your questions on our dynatrace community forum. this is where we typically handle these questions: https://community.compuwareapm.com/community/display/PUB/Community+Home

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on Stack Overflow. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts?. BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".